# How to fix the MetaPost "Missing argument to arrowhead" error?

Tags: mactex, metapost

I am playing the following code from page 15 in [Learning METAPOST by Doing](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/Courses/mptut.pdf)

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
  save arrowhead;
  vardef arrowhead(expr p) =
    save A,u,a,b; pair A,u; path a,b;
    A := point length(p)/2 of p;
    u := unitvector(direction length(p)/2 of p);
    a := A{-u}..(A - ahlength*u rotated 30);
    b := A{-u}..(A - ahlength*u rotated -30);
    (a & reverse(a) & b & reverse(b))--cycle
  enddef;
  u:=2cm; ahlength:=0.3cm;
  drawarrow (0,0)..(u,u)..(-u,u);
endfig; end;
```

But running `mpost arrow.mp` always gives the following error:

```
This is MetaPost, version 2.00 (TeX Live 2019) (kpathsea version 6.3.1)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./arrow.mp
! Missing argument to arrowhead.
<to be read again>
                   _apth
_finarr->...._apth(TEXT0);filldraw.arrowhead._apth
                                                  (TEXT0)
<to be read again>
                   ;
l.15   drawarrow (0,0)..(u,u)..(-u,u);

?
```

My Tex settings:

```
$ brew cask info mactex                                                                       
mactex: 2019.0508
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you are using is from 2005, so you can probably expect to find some incompatibilities with current METAPOST versions. In this case it is sufficient to remove the parentheses in the `arrowhead` definition.

MWE:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
  save arrowhead;
  vardef arrowhead expr p =
    save A,u,a,b; pair A,u; path a,b;
    A := point length(p)/2 of p;
    u := unitvector(direction length(p)/2 of p);
    a := A{-u}..(A - ahlength*u rotated 30);
    b := A{-u}..(A - ahlength*u rotated -30);
    (a & reverse(a) & b & reverse(b))--cycle
  enddef;
  u:=2cm; ahlength:=0.3cm;
  drawarrow (0,0)..(u,u)..(-u,u);
endfig; end;
```

Result:

[image]

See for other examples http://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html, which I used to find the correct syntax for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small improvement that put's the arrow in the middle of the path, rather than at the middle point:

```
vardef arrowhead expr p =
    save A,u,a,b,t; pair A,u; path a,b; numeric t;
    t = arctime 1/2 (arclength p + ahlength) of p;
    A := point t of p;
    u := unitvector(direction t of p);
    a := A{-u}..(A - ahlength*u rotated 30);
    b := A{-u}..(A - ahlength*u rotated -30);
    (a & reverse(a) & b & reverse(b))--cycle
enddef;
```

like so:

[image]

The new things are

- `arclength p` which returns the length of path `p` in PostScript points (instead of MP "time")
- `arctime x of p` which returns the time on `p` at which it gets to the given length `x`.